# Varnish object expires too soon. Log expiring objects, or show reason for expires?

Tags: wordpress, caching, varnish

I have issue with a wordpress website and it's cache module Varnish 4.0

I can achieve about 90% hit rate, but it still overloads my database on the backend.

Investigating the issue with Varnish it seems like some objects expires to soon. 
I have unset all cookies that the site is able to pass (except of the admin ones), I have also check random URLs and few file formats from the backend and they all don't seem to send cache control headers.

My bresp.ttl is set to 30 minutes.

However when I restart the varnish daemon and watch varnishstat the counter MAIN.n_expired starts growing in less than a minute.

I know I have to do some pass in order not to cache the administration page and search results, however the expires I think are something different and I am unable to find a tool, or a spell that will show me the expiring objects and the reason for their expiration.

Edit: 
Posting VCL file as requested:

```
        vcl 4.0;

        # Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
        backend default {
            .host = "127.0.0.1";
            .port = "8085";
            .connect_timeout = 60s;
            .first_byte_timeout = 60s;
            .between_bytes_timeout = 60s;
            .max_connections = 24000;
        }

        # Only allow purging from specific IPs
        acl purge {
            "localhost";
            "127.0.0.1";
            "10.0.0.113";
        }

        # This function is used when a request is send by a HTTP client (Browser) 
        sub vcl_recv {

            # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
            set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

            # Allow purging from ACL
            if (req.method == "PURGE") {
                # If not allowed then a error 405 is returned
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                    return(synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
                }   
                # If allowed, do a cache_lookup -> vlc_hit() or vlc_miss()
                return (purge);
            }

            # Post requests will not be cached
            if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
                return (pass);
            }

            # --- Wordpress specific configuration

            # Did not cache the RSS feed
            if (req.url ~ "/feed") {
                return (pass);
            }

            # Blitz hack
                if (req.url ~ "/mu-.*") {
                        return (pass);
                }


            # Did not cache the admin and login pages
            if (req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin)") {
                return (pass);
            }

            # pass wp-admin cookies
            if (req.http.cookie) {
                    if (req.http.cookie ~ "(wordpress_|wp-settings-)") {
                        return(pass);
                    } else {
                      unset req.http.cookie;
                    }
            }

                if ( !(req.url ~ "^/wp-admin") ) {
                        unset req.http.Cookie;
                }

            # Remove has_js and CloudFlare/Google Analytics __* cookies and statcounter is_unique
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js|is_unique)=[^;]*", "");

            # Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
            set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

            # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ga=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gat=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ym_uid=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__gfp_64b=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ym_isad=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ym_visorc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ym.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gat.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

              set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(__[a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
              set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_pk_(ses|id)[\.a-z0-9]*)=[^;]*", "");

            # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

            # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

            # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

            # Remove the wp test cookie
            set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

            # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
            if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
                    unset req.http.cookie;
            }

            # Cache the following files extensions 
            if (req.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ttf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)") {
                unset req.http.cookie;
            }

                # Set X-Forwarded-For header for logging in nginx
                unset req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
                set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

            # Normalize Accept-Encoding header and compression
            # https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html
            if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
                # Do no compress compressed files...
                if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
                        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
                } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
                        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
                } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
                        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
                } else {
                    unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
                }
            }

            # Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
            if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
                return (pass);
            }
            if (!req.http.cookie) {
                unset req.http.cookie;
            }

            # --- End of Wordpress specific configuration

            # Did not cache HTTP authentication and HTTP Cookie
            if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
                # Not cacheable by default
                return (pass);
            }

            # Cache all others requests
            return (hash);
        }

        sub vcl_pipe {
            return (pipe);
        }

        sub vcl_pass {
            return (fetch);

        }

        # The data on which the hashing will take place
        sub vcl_hash {
            hash_data(req.url);
            if (req.http.host) {
                hash_data(req.http.host);
            } else {
                hash_data(server.ip);
            }

            # If the client supports compression, keep that in a different cache
                if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
                    hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
            }

            return (lookup);
        }

        # This function is used when a request is sent by our backend (Nginx server)
        sub vcl_backend_response {
            # Remove some headers we never want to see
            unset beresp.http.Server;
            unset beresp.http.X-Powered-By;
        #   unset beresp.age;



            # Enable gzip support
                if (beresp.http.content-type ~"(text|javascript|application/x-font-woff)") {
                  set beresp.do_gzip = true;
                }



            # For static content strip all backend cookies
            if (bereq.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e?)g)|swf|ico") {
                unset beresp.http.cookie;
            }

            # Only allow cookies to be set if we're in admin area
            if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie && bereq.url !~ "^/wp-(login|admin)") {
                    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
                }

            # don't cache response to posted requests or those with basic auth
            if ( bereq.method == "POST" || bereq.http.Authorization ) {
                    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
                set beresp.ttl = 10s;
                set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Session";

                set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age = 120";

                return (deliver);
                }

                # don't cache search results
            if ( bereq.url ~ "\?s=" ){
                set beresp.uncacheable = true;
                        set beresp.ttl = 120s;


                set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable";
                set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age = 120";


                        return (deliver);
            }

            # long ttl for assets
            if (bereq.url ~ "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ttf|css|js|flv|mp3|mp4|pdf|ico|png)(\?.*|)$") {
            set beresp.ttl = 30d;
            set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age = 86400";
            }



            # only cache status ok
            if ( beresp.status != 200 ) {
                        set beresp.ttl = 1m;

                set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
                set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age = 120";
                set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age = 120";

                        return (deliver);

            }

            set beresp.ttl = 30m;
            # Define the default grace period to serve cached content
            set beresp.grace = 600s;

            set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
            set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age = 120";    
            set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age = 120";

            return (deliver);
        }

        # The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
        # Last chance to modify headers that are sent to the client
        sub vcl_deliver {
            if (obj.hits > 0) { 
                set resp.http.X-Cache = "cached";
            } else {
                set resp.http.x-Cache = "uncached";
            }

            # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
            unset resp.http.Server;

            # Remove some heanders: Varnish
            unset resp.http.Via;
            unset resp.http.X-Varnish;

            return (deliver);
        }

        sub vcl_init {
            return (ok);
        }

        sub vcl_fini {
            return (ok);
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete VCL you're using? Most likely the MAIN.n_expired that you're concerned with includes the hit for pass objects expiration. That is, if you have lines like these: ```set beresp.uncacheable = true; set beresp.ttl = 120s;```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I had lines like this indeed. 
However I removed the bresp.ttl and now it's only "uncacheable" but after I restarted varnishd I still got same results, in less than a minute the expired counter started growing. 
So my question still remains - do you have any idea how to monitor expiring URLs and the reason/status of expiry? 

Thanks